# DOMPDF how to include custom font

Tags: php, css, dompdf

1. I copied the folder for the dompdf library to **/dompdf**
2. a **/fonts** folder with Roboto-Black.ttf inside
3. I created a php file **index.php**

```
<?php
// Include autoloader 
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php'; 

// Reference the Dompdf namespace 
use Dompdf\Dompdf; 

// Instantiate and use the dompdf class 
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

// Load content from html file 
$html = file_get_contents("template.php"); 
$dompdf->loadHtml($html); 

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation 
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait'); 

// Render the HTML as PDF 
$dompdf->render(); 

// Output the generated PDF (1 = download and 0 = preview) 
$dompdf->stream("examplepdf", array("Attachment" => 0));
```

4. a real basic **template.php** file

```
<style>
    .customfont {
        color: #35aa45;
    }
</style>

<div class="customfont">
    this is my text
</div>
```

Now when i open the index.php file it create a pdf with a green text in default font. All ok!

Now i want to include a custom font to the template.

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        src: url('fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf') format('truetype');
    }

    .customfont {
        font-family: 'Roboto';
        color: #35aa45;
    }
</style>

<div class="customfont">
    this is my text
</div>
```

And now... blank screen, no PDF!
If i change the path for the font to a wrong folder.. the green text appears in a pdf like before.
I have now tried various options to include font, but for some reason it is not included! all other help here has not solved this problem.
does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What happens if you use a full path for url like `url('http://mysite/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf')`?

Comment: I also tried this ->blank screen! the path is correct, because only then will it be displayed incorrectly. maybe it is due to php settings or dompdf settings for custom fonts? it would be interesting if someone tried the exact same files if it would work

Comment: There are more information here that you can test: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! The solution was to add the tmp directory in my index.php

```
// Instantiate and use the dompdf class 
$dompdf = new Dompdf(array('tempDir'=>'/srv/www/xyz/tmp'));
```

thats all. now all regular custom fonts will work!

Comment: This seems quite random.. any info why this works? Or where you have found it.