# Dompdf doesn't embed custom font in pdf file

Tags: dompdf

I want to generate a pdf file with Charis SIL font. I put the TTF files in the root directory.
This is my php script:

```php
<?php

$ebook = <<<hd
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
<title>blablabla</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
@page { margin: 2.5cm; }
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Charis';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url(/CharisSIL-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Charis';
  font-style: italic, oblique;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url(/CharisSIL-Italic.ttf) format('truetype');
}
body { font-family: 'Charis', Times, serif; font-size: 20px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>bla bla bla bla bla</body>
</html>
hd;

use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
require_once("{$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]}/dompdf/autoload.inc.php");
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->getOptions()->setChroot($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
$dompdf->loadHtml($ebook);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();

?>
```

Dompdf generates the pdf with Times font and not with Charis.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59867770/dompdf-how-to-include-custom-font see using tempDir.

Comment: I have made this change: `$dompdf = new Dompdf(array('tempDir'=>'$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]/temp'));`. The folder "temp" already exists. But it still doesn't work.